# Display items with id from an array

Tags: php, mysql

So i created a column in my database that accepts JSON array, inside these array are item id's , i want to create a loop on those ids and insert it in an sql select statements to display all items that has the ids in the array, but im clueless on how to do it.

```
$sql = "SELECT bookmarks FROM `accounts` WHERE firstname='".$firstname."' && lastname='".$lastname."' ";

$sth = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
```

```
foreach($rows as $key ){ ?????
$bookmark = "SELECT * FROM books id='".$key."'";
$bookselect = mysqli_query($conn, $bookmark);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($bookselect)) { 


}
}????
```

Comment: may you print_r()  or var_dump() your rows table?

Comment: Error 1(You need to add WHERE): $bookmark = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE id='".$key."'";

Comment: Your code is potentially wide open to [SQL Injection](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection) attack due to the use of raw user supplied data being used directly in the sql. To help mitigate this threat you should always use [Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). A useful guide, with plenty of example code, is [PHP Delusions](https://phpdelusions.net/)

Comment: print json_encode($rows);  Output: [{"bookmarks":"[5]"}]

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion. I dont know how to loop through that json array

Comment: Use: $rd = json_decode($r['bookmarks'], true);
        foreach($rd as $ids){
            $rows[] = $ids;
        } // Insted of $rows[] = $r;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are storing array in Database, You need to convert that into array and ids first:

Check below code for example:

```
     $sql = "SELECT bookmarks FROM `accounts` WHERE firstname='".$firstname."' && lastname='".$lastname."' ";

    $sth = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $rows = array();
    while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
        $rd = json_decode($r['bookmarks'], true);
        foreach($rd as $ids){
            $rows[] = $ids;
        }
    }

    $bookmark = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE id IN('".implode("','",$rows)."'";
    $bookselect = mysqli_query($conn, $bookmark);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($bookselect)) { 
        print_r($row);
    
    
    }
```

Comment: i have an idea on how to store those arrays in database, what i want is retrieve it, loop through those array of ids and display the items that have those ids in the html

Comment: btw sir can you explain this to me, why it has a "true" parameter  $rd = json_decode($r['bookmarks'], true);

Comment: It's because we want result as an array, If we don't pass true then it will return as object